Accounting for deletions in recurring meetings that repeat 'n' times
I have several classes which end after 25 sessions. Holidays and cancellations just push the counter back, but I have to do this in my head and often get it wrong.
Recurring meeting "TEST", repeat daily, end after 4 times
MTWTh
MXWTH <- I delete a session
MxWThF <- the goal

The best "solution" I've found thus far is whenever I delete a session (for a holiday/cancellation),  update it to end after N+number of holidays and save "for all meetings". This works (deletions are not overwritten) but still leaves me open to miscounts. I can, of course, keep track on paper, but...
Is there a way to get Google Calendar to update the count on a recurring meeting that ends after N sessions? Alternatively, is there a tool to count or display the number of sessions?
